# How to determine if two nodes are connected to each other?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This code finds the shortest path but it does not take into account if the destination can even be reached. How could I check if the destination is reachable before running this function?

```
   void Trains::shortestPath(int src, int dest)
{
    set< pair<int, int> > setds;
    vector<int> dist(V, INF);
    setds.insert(make_pair(0, src));
    dist[src] = 0;
    while (!setds.empty())
    {
        pair<int, int> tmp = *(setds.begin());
        setds.erase(setds.begin());
        int u = tmp.second;
        list< pair<int, int> >::iterator i;
        for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
        {
            int v = (*i).first;
            int weight = (*i).second;
            if (dist[v] > dist[u] + weight)
            {
                if (dist[v] != INF)
                    setds.erase(setds.find(make_pair(dist[v], v)));
                dist[v] = dist[u] + weight;
                setds.insert(make_pair(dist[v], v));
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Vertex   Distance from Source\n");
        printf("%d \t\t %d\n", dest, dist[dest]);
}
```

Output:

```
Vertex   Distance from Source
4        73
```

This is slightly modified from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-using-set-in-stl/ if you want to see all the code.

Comment: What do you suppose `if (dist[v] != INF)` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is run dfs from source and watch is node destination is visited, it runs in O(N + M) before Dijkstra`s algorithm.
 If your graph is not oriented, split it to connected components once by O(N + M) and check before run your algorithm, if source and destination in same components by O(1). 

Advice:
better use priority_queue instead set, it will be faster.